# Why my authentication service works fine locally on my machine but on Kubernetes pod it thows [ERROR] 13:53:13 ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript

Tags: typescript, mongodb, kubernetes, mongoose

I developed an authentication service using typescript/express app and mongodb/mongoose, and created a user model with some customizations with mongoose. When I run the app locally everything works fine like so:

```bash
> auth@1.0.0 start
> ts-node-dev --files src/index.ts

[INFO] 16:02:56 ts-node-dev ver. 2.0.0 (using ts-node ver. 10.9.1, typescript ver. 5.2.2)
Service listening on port 3000!
Connected to MongoDb
```

However when I try to run it by kubernetes via minikube it throws this error:

```bash
> auth@1.0.0 start
> ts-node-dev --files src/index.ts

[INFO] 14:11:17 ts-node-dev ver. 2.0.0 (using ts-node ver. 10.9.1, typescript ver. 5.2.2)
Compilation error in /app/src/routes/signin.ts
[ERROR] 14:11:20 ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/routes/signin.ts(25,55): error TS2339: Property 'password' does not exist on type 'Document<unknown, unknown, unknown> & Omit<{ _id: ObjectId; }, never>'.
src/routes/signin.ts(34,25): error TS2339: Property 'email' does not exist on type 'Document<unknown, unknown, unknown> & Omit<{ _id: ObjectId; }, never>'.
```

### Here is

##### index.ts

```js
import "express-async-errors";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import app from "./app";

const startDb = async () => {
  if (!process.env.JWT_KEY) {
    throw new Error("JWT_KEY must be defined");
  }

  if (!process.env.MONGO_URI) {
    throw new Error("MONGO_URI must be defined");
  }
  
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI);
    console.log("Connected to MongoDb");
    
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}

const port = 3000;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Service listening on port ${port}!`);
});

startDb();
```

##### app.ts

```js
import express from "express";
import "express-async-errors";
import { json } from 'body-parser';
import cookieSession from "cookie-session";
import { errorHandler, NotFoundError } from "@euticketing/common";

import { currentuserRouter } from "./routes/current-user";
import { signinRouter } from "./routes/signin";
import { signoutRouter } from "./routes/signout";
import { signupRouter } from "./routes/signup";

const app = express();

// To trust requests coming from Nginx proxy
app.set("trust proxy", true);

app.use(json());

app.use(cookieSession({
  signed: false,
  secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "test",
}))

app.use(currentuserRouter);
app.use(signinRouter);
app.use(signoutRouter);
app.use(signupRouter);

app.all("*", async () => {
  throw new NotFoundError();
})

app.use(errorHandler);

export default app;
```

##### routes/signin.ts

```js
import express, { Request, Response } from "express";
import { body } from "express-validator";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import { validateRequest, BadRequestError } from "@euticketing/common";
import { User } from "../models/user";
import { Password } from "../utils/password";


const router = express.Router();

const validation = [
  body("email").isEmail().withMessage("Must be a valid email"),
  body("password").trim().notEmpty().withMessage("Must supply a valid password"),
];

router.post("/api/users/signin", validation, validateRequest, async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email });

  if (!existingUser) {
    throw new BadRequestError("Invalid credentials");
  }

  const isMatch = await Password.compare(existingUser.password, password);

  if (!isMatch) {
    throw new BadRequestError("Invalid credentials");
  }

  // 1. Generate a JWT token
  const userJwt = jwt.sign({
    id: existingUser.id,
    email: existingUser.email,
  }, process.env.JWT_KEY!);

  // 2. Store it on a session cookie
  req.session = {
    jwt: userJwt
  }

  res.status(200).send(existingUser);
});

export { router as signinRouter }
```

##### models/user.ts

```js
import mongoose, { Schema, model } from 'mongoose';
import { Password } from '../utils/password';

interface IUser {
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

const userSchema = new Schema<IUser>({
  email: { type: String, required: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
}, {
  // Mutate the view of returning document representation
  toJSON: {
    transform(doc, ret) {
      ret.id = ret._id;
      delete ret._id;
      delete ret.password;
      delete ret.__v;
    },
  }
});

// An interface that define User document
interface IUserDoc extends mongoose.Document {
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

// Workaround to add build() static function into User Model
interface IUserModel extends mongoose.Model<IUserDoc> {
  build(user: IUser): IUserDoc;
}

// Encrypt password before saving in database
userSchema.pre("save", async function (done) {
  if (this.isModified("password")) {
    const hashed = await Password.toHash(this.get("password"));
    this.set("password", hashed);
  }

  done();
});

userSchema.statics.build = (user: IUser) => {
  return new User(user);
}

const User = model<IUserDoc, IUserModel>('User', userSchema);

export { User };
```

##### package.json

```json
{
  "name": "auth",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node-dev --files src/index.ts",
    "test": "jest --watchAll --no-cache"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "ts-jest",
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "./src/test/setup.ts"
    ]
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/cookie-session": "^2.0.45",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.4",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "@types/mongoose": "^5.11.97",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.12",
    "jest": "^29.6.4",
    "mongodb-memory-server": "^8.15.1",
    "supertest": "^6.3.3",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.1",
    "ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@euticketing/common": "^1.0.1",
    "cookie-session": "^2.0.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-async-errors": "^3.1.1",
    "express-validator": "^7.0.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "mongoose": "^7.5.0"
  }
}
```